# how to squeeze a Dataframe into Series with binding element as tuple and recover it?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to transform two-dimensional dataframe into one-dimensional Series.

let me list an example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(9), (3,3)))

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

what i want is a seies like this:

```
In [13]: pd.Series([(0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8)])
Out[13]: 
0    (0, 1, 2)
1    (3, 4, 5)
2    (6, 7, 8)
dtype: object
```

which merge all element in one row into a tuple, so we reduce the dimension from 2 -> 1

is there good methods can do this?

and, how can i recover the dataframe by the tuple series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `List comprehension` with [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to convert it to `Series`:

```
In [556]: l = [tuple(r) for r in df.to_numpy()]

In [563]: new_series = pd.Series(l)

In [564]: new_series
Out[564]: 
0    (0, 1, 2)
1    (3, 4, 5)
2    (6, 7, 8)
dtype: object
```

To convert it back to `df`, pass the `list` to the dataframe constructor:

```
In [561]: pd.DataFrame(l)
Out[561]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Comment: I think `df['x']=df.agg(tuple,1)` would be faster and neater

Comment: @wwnde I've edited my answer to use `to_numpy` for performance. This should be better.

Comment: thx for this great method. but could you let me know why df.agg is worse in performance than df.to_numpy() loop? i think agg is also a vectorize operation?

Comment: @xyhuang As you know `pandas` is `numpy` under the hood. `to_numpy` method was introduced to extract the underlying NumPy array from DataFrames.